# Code doesn't print the last sequence in a file

Tags: python, algorithm, file-io, text-processing, text-parsing

I have a file that looks like this:

```
<s0> 3
line1
line2
line3 
<s1> 5
line1
line2
<s2> 4
etc. up to more than a thousand
```

Each sequence has a header like `<s0> 3`, which in this case states that three lines follow. In the example above, the number of lines below `<s1>` is two, so I have to correct the header to `<s1> 2`.

The code I have below picks out the sequence headers and the correct number of lines below them. But for some reason, it never gets the details of the last sequence. I know something is wrong but I don't know what. Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong?

```
import re

def call():
with open('trial_perl.txt') as fp:
    docHeader = open("C:\path\header.txt","w")
    c = 0
    c1 = 0
    header = []
    k = -1
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith("<s"):
            #header = line.split(" ")
            #print header[1]
            c = 0
        else:
            c1 = c + 1
            c += 1

        if c == 0 and c1>0:
            k +=1
            printing = c1
            if printing >= 0:
                s = "<s%s>" % (k)
            #print "%s %d" % (s, printing)

                docHeader.write(s+" "+str(printing)+"\n")

call()
```

Comment: Guys so many thanks for your inputs I really appreciate them, they helped depend my knowledge and understanding, and more of logical thinking. I have been able to solve this just by adding docHeader.write("<d_%s> %d\n" % (k+1, c1)) when exiting the for loop. With your inputs, my coding is getting better!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you have no sentinel at the end of the last sequence in your data, so your code will need to deal with the last sequence AFTER the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest some python tricks to get to your results; you don't need those c/c1/k counter variables, as they make the code more difficult to read and maintain. Instead, populate a map of sequence header to sequence items and then use the map to do all your work:

(this code works only if all sequence headers are unique - if you have duplicates, it won't work)

```
with open('trial_perl.txt') as fp:
    docHeader = open("C:\path\header.txt","w")
    data = {}
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith("<s"):
            current_sequence = line
            # create a list with the header as the key
            data[current_sequence] = []
        else:
            # add each sequence to the list we defined above
            data[current_sequence].append(line)
```

Your map is ready! It looks like this:

```
{"<s0> 3": ["line1", "line2", "line5"],
 "<s1> 5": ["line1", "line2"]}
```

You can iterate it like this:

```
for header, lines in data.items():
    # header is the key, or "<s0> 3"
    # lines is the list of lines under that header ["line1", "line2", etc]
    num_of_lines = len(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you neglect to check the value of `c` after you have read the last line. You probably had difficulty spotting this problem because of all the superfluous code. You don't have to increment `k`, since you can extract the value from the `<s...>` tag. And you don't have to have all three variables `c`, `c1`, and `printing`. A single `count` variable will do.

```
import re, sys

def call():
    with open('trial_perl.txt') as fp:
        docHeader = sys.stdout #open("C:\path\header.txt","w")
        count = 0
        id = None
        for line in fp:
            if line.startswith("<s"):
                if id != None:
                    tag = '<s%s>' % id
                    docHeader.write('<s%d> %d\n' % (id, count))
                count = 0
                id = int(line[2:line.find('>')])
            else:
                count += 1
        if id != None:
            tag = '<s%s>' % id
            docHeader.write('<s%d> %d\n' % (id, count))

call()
```

Comment: Hi @Laszlo, I didn't quite get an output with your code. I increament K because the value after each sequence header is not always correct. So I need to make sure to get the current number of lines by counting.

Comment: I increment `count` to track the number of lines. You are using `k` for the header number, but I extract it directly from the header. That's why I don't need `k`.

Comment: Also, do you notice that I'm using `sys.stdout` to verify the output? You'll have to change that line back to `docHeader = open("C:\path\header.txt","w")` if you want the output to get written to "header.txt".

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `groupby` from itertools, where you take the maximum number of line in each group - a group corresponding to a sequence of header + line in your file: :

```
from itertools import groupby

def call():
    with open('stack.txt') as fp:
        header = [-1]
        lines  = [0]
        for line in fp:
            if line.startswith("<s"):
                header.append(header[-1]+1)
                lines.append(0)
            else:
                header.append(header[-1])
                lines.append(lines[-1] +1)

    with open('result','w') as f:
        for key, group in groupby(zip(header[1:],lines[1:]), lambda x: x[0]):
            f.write(str(("<s%d> %d\n" % max(group))))

    f.close()

call()

#<s0> 3
#<s1> 2
```

`stack.txt` is the file containing your data:

```
<s0> 3
line1
line2
line3 
<s1> 5
line1
line2
```

Comment: Hi Colonel, an not able to get the output printed

Comment: @EbukaI do you mean by pasting and making my code running nothing appears? I forgot to mention I run it in terminal with command `python myscript.py`

Comment: I dunno how you run your code (using an editor + consola, or directly in Python consola, or using and IDE). I updated the code so that results are save in `result` file, in the same folder as your script is.